# how to Deleting and destroying embedded documents in Mongoid with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I m using relation `( has_many , belongs_to)` tha's working with source code above here, but I get `error document Not Found` for delete Photo(picture) when change relations (`embeds_many, embedded_in`). Anybody Helpme please, how to use `Embed_many relations` using mongoid & what's wrong my source code here :

```
class Room
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :home_type, type: String
  field :room_type, type: String
  embeds_many :photos
end

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip


  embedded_in :room


end

class PhotosController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
        @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
        room = @photo.room

        @photo.destroy
        @photos = Photo.where(room_id: room.id)
        respond_to :js
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer here is that when you embed a document you are adding that document within another one. In order for mongodb to find the embedded document it first needs to find the parent. In your previous iteration you with has_many you are associating two documents from different collections, with enables you to look up by the associated document.

Therefore although embedded documents have an _id, you are only able to look them up from within the document. If you were to output @photo you would see that it was nil. I am surprised that your second line room = @photo.room is not returning an error no method for nil:NilClass.

To do what you want, you first need to find the document, which you could do without too much change:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
        room = Room.find_by('photo._id': BSON::ObjectId(params[:id]))
        @photo = room.photos.find(params[:id])

        @photo.destroy
        @photos = room.photos
        respond_to :js
    end
end
```